# labelling x and y axis of the wtr.heat.map - no error detected but nothing changes on my heat map

Tags: r, heatmap

I'm using the following code to create a heat map with rlakeanalyzer. I'm having problems when I add functions.

When I run

```
TalusSouthHeatMap <- wtr.heat.map(TalusSouthdf)
```

I get a graph with a labelled y axis (Depth m). When I add the zlim function the y axis label disappears, and when I try to add the ylab, xlab and plot title nothing happens. No error is detected but nothing on my plot view changes.

This is the code I'm using when all the functions are added.

```
TalusSouthHeatMap <- wtr.heat.map(TalusSouthdf, zlim=c(0,20), xlab='Date', 
ylab="Depth (m)", plot.title="Talus South Water Temp (C)")
```

Sanpshot of my data structure
'data.frame':   8682 obs. of  8 variables:
$ datetime..GMT.: POSIXct, format: "2023-07-06 20:50:40" "2023-07-06 21:05:40" "2023-07-06 21:20:40" "2023-07-06 21:35:40" ...
$ wtr_0.0       : num  9.57 9.57 9.57 9.57 9.47 ...
$ wtr_1.0       : num  9.67 9.57 9.57 9.57 9.57 ...
$ wtr_2.0       : num  9.28 9.47 9.47 9.47 9.47 ...
$ wtr_3.0       : num  8.68 8.78 8.78 8.58 8.48 ...
$ wtr_4.0       : num  8.58 8.48 8.28 8.08 7.98 ...
$ wtr_5.0       : num  7.88 7.58 7.38 7.48 7.38 ...
$ wtr_6.0       : num  7.18 7.08 7.28 7.28 7.38 ...

wtr_0.0 = depth
num = temperatures at depths

[image: Heat Map of Lake]

dput(TalusSouthdf)snap shot

7.882, 7.882, 7.882, 7.882, 7.983, 7.983, 7.882, 7.882, 7.983,
8.082, 8.082, 8.082, 8.182, 8.182, 8.182, 8.282, 8.182, 8.182,
8.182, 8.282, 8.282, 8.382, 8.481, 8.481, 8.581, 8.68, 8.581,
8.68, 8.779, 8.779, 8.779, 8.581, 8.581, 8.68, 8.779, 8.581,
8.481, 8.282, 8.182, 8.382, 8.481, 8.779, 8.282, 8.282, 8.581,
8.282, 8.182, 8.282, 8.082, 7.983, 7.983, 7.983, 7.983, 8.182,
8.182, 8.282, 8.082, 7.782, 7.782, 8.182, 8.282, 8.182, 7.983,
8.082, 8.182, 8.182, 8.282, 8.282, 8.382, 8.282, 8.282, 8.282,
8.082, 7.983, 8.082, 8.082, 8.082, 7.983, 7.983, 8.082, 8.082,
7.983, 7.983, 7.983, 8.082, 8.082, 8.182, 8.082, 8.182, 8.182,
8.082, 8.082, 8.082, 7.983, 8.082, 8.182, 8.182, 8.082, 8.182,
,
4.415, 4.415, 4.415, 4.415, 4.415)), row.names = c(NA, -8682L
), class = "data.frame")

Comment: It will be much easier to help if you provide at least a short, representative sample of your data. Please [edit] your question and paste the output of the `dput(data)` command (preferred) or in tab delimited form. This will help users here answer your question.

Comment: @M-- I'm very new to R so I'm not sure what dput(data) command (preferred) or in tab delimited form" means, however, I will put a snapshot of my data str. and hopefully that will help

Comment: Just run `dput(TalusSouthdf)` and paste its results here.

Comment: @M-- The output was too many characters so I added a snap shot above of dput(TalusSouthdf)

Comment: Unfortunately, snapshot doesn't work with dput, try `dput(head(TalusSouthdf))` instead. BTW, there's no character limit that I am aware of, for a question.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is that while you can set the x axis title using `xlab=`, you can't set the y axis title using `ylab=`. The latter is hard-coded in `wtr.heat.map` and defaults to `"Depth (m)"`. But you can set it via `plot.title=`. Unfortunately that is not mentioned in the docs.

Moreover, you can't pass a character string to `plot.title=`. Instead, it requires (see `?filled.contour`)

> statements which add titles to the main plot.

From the examples you have to do `plot.title = title(main = ....)`. And `plot.title=` can also be used to set the axis titles, i.e. `plot.title = title(main = ...., xlab = ..., ylab = ...)`.

Using a minimal reproducible example based on the default example from `?wtr.heat.map`:

```
library(rLakeAnalyzer)

wtr.path <- system.file("extdata", "Sparkling.daily.wtr", package = "rLakeAnalyzer")
TalusSouthdf <- load.ts(wtr.path)

wtr.heat.map(TalusSouthdf,
  zlim = c(0, 20),
  plot.title = title(
    main = "Talus South Water Temp (C)",
    xlab = "Date",
    ylab = "Depth (m)"
  )
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, I had been struggling with that for quite some time!

Comment: I would like to add a precipitation trendline on the top of the heat map. I've looked through the rLakeAnalyzer document and can't find anything helpful. Do you know how I would go about doing this?